# Querying data with list of ids from different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do something like thisin MySQL. Query on one table with a list of ids from another table. The Group_Concat return a list of comma separated ids that i want to use in my first select. My try results in an error.

(Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.id SEPARATOR ',')   FROM m.my_aspnet_detai' at line 2)

How does one write this with correct syntax?

```
SELECT * FROM m.my_aspnet_membership m 
where m.userId = IN
(
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.id SEPARATOR ',')
  FROM m.my_aspnet_details t
 WHERE t.customerid = '2'
);
```

Comment: I don't think this use of in statement is possible.. I think it will see it as a string and not values seperated by comma. Try using instr(concate...,cast to string of the id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT * FROM m.my_aspnet_membership m 
where m.userId = IN
(
SELECT t.id 
  FROM m.my_aspnet_details t
 WHERE t.customerid = '2'
);
```

Or even better to use JOIN

```
SELECT * 
FROM m.my_aspnet_membership 
         INNER JOIN m.my_aspnet_details t ON t.id=m.userId
WHERE t.customerid = '2'
```

Comment: Thank you StanislavL! The JOIN version works great. With the IN version i get a error. Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN ( SELECT t.id    FROM m.my_aspnet_details t  WHERE t.customerid = ' at line 2